# Problem with cin ignoring whitespace in my prompt

Tags: c++, input, cin

I am very new to C++ and I am having trouble understanding the reason as to why I'm not getting my desired output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "you are " << age << " years old";
    return 0;
}
```

The output I WOULD LIKE to see is;

```
Enter your age: 19
you are 19 years old
```

However, the output I GET is the following;

```
Enter your age:19
 you are 19 years old
```

## EDIT

This was a specific issue due to the IDE I was using (CLion). The output was fixed when executed in a shell. Restarting the IDE also fixed the issue.

Comment: Try `cout << "Enter your age: " << flush;` -- it's probably a buffering issue.

Comment: I get exactly what you would like to see, and that is what it should output. How are you executing your program? Did you forget to recompile?

Comment: I just tried your suggestion paddy suggestions and it didn't work

Comment: please be precise. You see `Enter your age: 19` not `Enter your age:19` with your code, right?

Comment: I am running it through CLion using mingw as the compiler, hope that answers your question molbdnilo

Comment: No, I see     Enter your age:19

Comment: well ok, so your ouput has one space too little and one too much. Sorry, I had to ask, because it isnt obvious how to explain what you see

Comment: Just to clarify `Enter your age:19` is what I see when answering the input request, and ` you are 19 years old` is what I see after I hit enter

Comment: Are you running this program inside your IDE?  Maybe try running it in an actual shell.

Comment: Just ran it in a shell and it worked fine, thank you